# Mapping screen pixels to openGL coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to map screen pixels to openGL coordinates. Basically I have a 3D sphere drawn at position Vector3f(0,0,0) and radius=1 using glut.

```
glutSolidSphere(radius/*1*/,50,50);
```

This sphere, rather than appearing at the center of the screen appears in the top left quadrant of the screen. My goal is to convert a mouse click's location to openGL coordinates to find out what object on screen was clicked. I followed the [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/102830/) here to calculate the openGL coordinates using the formula

```
converted_x = 2.0f/screen_width*mouse_x - 1.0f
converted_y = 2.0f/screen_width*mouse_y - 1.0f
```

When I try to click on the center of the sphere, I get the click position (converted_x,converted_y) as (-0.62185,-0.607500) i.e., pixel location (mouse_x, mouse_y) is (242, 157). My screen  resolution is 1280*800. **I am not able to figure how I can use this information to figure out that the sphere was clicked.** Any help is much appreciated.

Currently this is the code I have in reshape(), taken from an existing project.

```
void reshape(int w, int h)  
{
    // Adjust the viewport if the user resizes the window
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
    glLoadIdentity();  
    if (h==0)  
        gluPerspective(80,(float)w,1.0,5000.0);
    else
        gluPerspective (80,( float )w /( float )h,1.0,5000.0 );
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);  
    glLoadIdentity(); 
}
```

Comment: Since 3D to 2D projection occurs, each pixel is a result of projecting a line. So you have to figure out which line projects in the pixel clicked, then calculate intersection between the line and your objects. That formula you found does not apply to your case.

Comment: Thanks! I realize that now. I have to figure out how to get the projection line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187072/opengl-ray-pick this might be relevant. Or you could search for "OpenGL ray picking"

Comment: Mouse coordinates are already one of many "OpenGL coordinates". One caveat is that mouse coordinates (as you would get from a window system event) usually have the origin at the top-left, OpenGL's window-space coordinates have the origin at the bottom-left, so you may have to negate the y-axis. But I think what you are really asking for here is how to convert window-space coordinates to view-, world- or object-space; that is done by "unprojection" (reverse the viewport transform, projection and modelling transformations).

Comment: GLU has a function literally called `gluUnProject (...)`. You might want to take a look at that and see if it looks like what you are after. I can help you by explaining how it works if need be, but there are a lot of answers on Stack Overflow that already do this.

Comment: See also: http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/picking_alpha_blending_alpha_testing_sorting/16005/ ; note that much of the NeHe tutorial stuff is dated, but I should think that for you are after the picking tutorial should be fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! gluUnProject was what I was looking for! Thank you! @Andon M. Coleman. Thanks to everybody!!